# Artifactory NuGet install not getting latest package version

Tags: nuget, artifactory

I am experiencing a problem when installing NuGet packages from a self-hosted Artifactory. When a package ID gets above thirty unique versions the NuGet install command becomes unable to identify the latest version. Examining the log from NuGet install command I can see it making two web requests.

```
GET https://artifactory.local/artifactory/api/nuget/<repository>/FindPackagesById()?id='<package ID>'
OK https://artifactory.local/artifactory/api/nuget/<repository>/FindPackagesById()?id='<package ID>' 815ms
GET https://artifactory.local/artifactory/api/nuget/<repository>/FindPackagesById()?$skip=80&id='<package ID>'
OK https://artifactory.local/artifactory/api/nuget/<repository>/FindPackagesById()?$skip=80&id='<package ID>' 209 ms
```

When I run these commands I get a XML feed response with thirty and zero entries respectively. If I adjust the '$skip' parameter in the second request to thirty I see my most recent packages.

Is Artifactory incorrectly implementing the NuGet API FindPackagesById method by not returning eighty entries?

Specs

- Artifactory version 4.12.01
- NuGet command line version 3.4.4.1321

Comment: Does this happens with a virtual repository?

Comment: It does happen with a virtual repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation with Local and Virtual Nuget repositories mandates a max of 80 results per page. The first OData feed response (for the first request that has no $skip param in it) should be able to return 80 entries, providing that there are at least 80 versions of the package.

A problem that Artifactory currently has and that we are aware of happens when a single package (same package ID) is contained within multiple different repositories, and when the request is sent via a Virtual repository that aggregates those repositories. If the single package has more than 80 versions, Artifactory returns a pagination link with $skip=80 on the first response. The issue is that Artifactory (wrongly) assumes that a certain package ID will only exist in one repository under the virtual repo, and hence sends $skip=n to all the aggregated repos one by one, so skip=1 actually skips two entities, skip=2 actually skips 4, and skip=n essentially becomes skip=2n. This bug is reported here and will be fixed in the coming months:

https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-12379

If this doesn't sound like your problem, please share how many versions exist for the package you are trying to install, whether you are using a virtual repository or not, and whether the same package exists in more than one repository under the corresponding virtual repo.

Until RTFACT-12379 is fixed, the current (not so ideal) workarounds for this are either not using a virtual repository to install packages that have more than 80 versions, or making sure that a certain package does not exist in more than one repository.

Comment: This occurs when using a virtual repository but this does not sound exactly like my situation. The first query does not specify any skip parameters but returns a result with only 30 entries out 34 packages. The packages exist only in one repository of the three under the virtual repository. Virtual repository points to a remote repository which points to a local repository hosting the packages.

If $skip=30 is specified I do see the other 4 packages.

Comment: @MatthewRyan Is the remote endpoint that hosts those packages an Artifactory endpoint? If yes, do you know what Artifatory version? I'm asking because older Artifactory versions used to limit page size to 30 IIRC. I'd try querying that endpoint's local repo directly (using the same FindPackagesById() request) and see whether it returns a max of 30 results for the first page. Also, try querying the remote repo (not the virtual) on your server directly and see whether that produces a correct $skip value of 30.

Comment: This sounds like this is probably the issue. We are in the process of upgrading our two Artifactory instances so they are on different major versions. The remote repository does not not use "$skip" instead it specifies an explicit version of the package to continue from using "$skiptoken".

Comment: @MatthewRyan yes, $skiptoken is the previous pagination convention that is nowadays replaced with $skip. Neither Artifactory or the NuGet gallery use it anymore. In that case, upgrading the second instance sounds like the way to go here.